# How to launch another app within an app with the targets ID in blackberry10

Tags: c++, pthreads, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to invoke an app within a thread of another app. I have the target app's unique id. I do not need to do modifications in the source code of the target app.

How do I launch the target app?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it work? How *didn't* it work (often as important to know)? You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: You should also familiarize yourself with the invokation framework: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/index.html

Comment: Invocation Framework requires a source code editing to receive invocation right? I need a way to figure out without editing it